# Any lightweight firewall alternative to Ashampoo firewall

Tags: windows-8, networking, firewall

I've been using Ashampoo firewall all the time and happy with that. This application alerts me when an application is requesting internet. I have the option to allow the requesting application and remember my choice for this app. That's all I want. Now I've upgraded to Windows 8 and Ashampoo firewall is not compatible anymore. Is there any lightweight and user friendly firewall software alternative to Ashampoo? I don't need a firewall that monitors my browser etc.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't like the built-in windows firewall?

Comment: Yes. I also want to filter some of windows build in apps also.

Comment: And build-in firewall do not have my requirement `This application alerts me when an application is requesting internet`

Comment: yep, the Windows firewall does alert when a new app first requests network access. Do you need to make that decision every time the app starts? It doesn't do that, but it does certainly allow you to know the first time.

Comment: @MichaelKohne No, it doesn't. It only popups when a program tries to **listen** on a closed port, but not when a program tries to connect to internet, which happens to be what the OP wants and also where software firewalls add the more protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Comodo Firewall, it has everything that you need, and is available for the low, low price of free. It does monitor your browser but you can turn that off, and it is off by default anyway. It's not extremely lightweight, but I can use it on some low-end PCs. There's also ZoneAlarm Firewall and PrivateFirewall, both are free, and are very good. I don't believe ZoneAlarm tells you when an app requests network access, but PrivateFirewall certainly does that and monitors processes for malicious activity. Also, most paid Internet Security suites provide a firewall built-in, with all or most of the features you need. ESET Personal Firewall is a good one as well as Avira's. All of the above are compatible with Windows 8.1 but not Windows 8 (the update to 8.1 is free in the Windows Store).

Answer (score 1):

I use a free edition application called Glasswire application.  It works well under Windows 7 or 8, and is a good alternative to the integrated firewall or other existing solution that consumes a lot of resource.  The software enjoys a good user interface is easy to handle.  For more information here is the link https://www.glasswire.com/features

Comment: Free version of GlassWire doesn't show any popups, you just have to monitor the list of connections yourself and click any particular app if you want to block it (i.e. when it's already too late). At first glance the app seems good but it isn't particularly user friendly, or easy to customize and filter outgoing connections.